# What is the type of the seaplane at the end of runway 18L on Schiphol Airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane, eham

From 47 to 52 seconds into this video we can see a seaplane parked in a small pool of water. What type of plane is this and when did the plane fly for the last time?

Answer (score 16):

To clarify, it's a Fokker F-27 Friendship 500.

Manufacturered in 1971, PH-NIV has photos of it on [Wiki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:PH-NIV_(aircraft)):

[image]

[Registration details here](https://www.planelogger.com/Aircraft/Registration/'PH-NIV'/696740?seo=F-27%20Friendship-500_Fokker%20Logistics%20Park)

As to how it's in Amsterdam Schipol:

> towed to entrance at Oude Meer nr Schiphol East 12.07.12 as PH-NIV in
>   old Fokker proto cs owner Coöperatieve Vereniging Anthony Fokker
>   Logistics UA moved to permanent display location 13.03.13 on poles in
>   a lake with nose up,

So it's been there since March 13, 2013 (the same day the current pope was inaugurated, incidentally).

Before that, it was registered with several companies during its service:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The aircraft is not actually a seaplane but a Fokker F-27 (PH-NIV) which is mounted on posts in the middle of a small lagoon.

It was built in 1971 and delivered to Air France. I couldn't find a last flight, but it was registered to Fokker in 2012, although there's no indication whether it was flying at that point.

For copyright reasons I haven't included images here, but photos can be seen at [JetPhotos](https://www.jetphotos.com/registration/PH-NIV)